# Assign value to type byte[] in c#

Tags: c#

How can I set a value to a byte[]

I have tried the following but I get a compilation error:

```
byte[] XMLbyte=null;
XMLbyte = byte(2345)
```

Any suggestions how I can do this?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 4):

You must XMLbyte = new byte[2345];

maybe you want a bytearray from "2345" string ?

```
System.Text.UTF8Encoding  encoding=new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
XMLbyte = encoding.GetBytes("2345");
```

Answer (score 1):

Some options to initialize an array:

```
XMLbyte = new byte[50]; // creates an array with 50 elements, all values are zero.
XMLbyte = new byte[3] {1,2,3}; // creates an array with 3 elements: 1,2,3
XMLbyte = new byte[] {1,2,3}; // creates an array with 3 elements: 1,2,3
XMLbyte = {1,2,3}; // creates an array with 3 elements: 1,2,3
```

Answer (score 0):

`byte[]` is an array of bytes.  You might want just the `byte` type.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems silly but I think you are missing the **new** operator

```
XMLbyte = new byte[2345]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the [GetBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/de8fssa4.aspx) method:

```
byte[] XMLbyte = BitConverter.GetBytes(2345);
```

Comment: I believe you have went too far. I seriously doubt that his intention was to get the 4 bytes that represent an integer "under the hood".

Comment: @Yodan, let's leave the OP explain.

Answer (score 0):

try below code

```
byte[] XMLbyte=null;  
 XMLbyte = new byte[2] {1,2}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `byte[] temp = new byte [255];`

Or this: `byte[] temp = new byte [123];`